# 'Provide us the ability' vs 'provide us with the ability'

Tags: difference

In an old stackexchange question (I don't remember which one) someone had posted an image of their English question paper. They wanted to know why the multiple-choice option 'd' would not work. This issue, I believe was resolved.

The question began with the sentence 'Vitamin C provides us the ability to *resist disease*'(The portion in italics is a modified reproduction of the original statement which I forgot).

What confused me was the usage 'provides us the ability'. Wouldn't 'provides us **with** the ability' be grammatically right? Or is the former usage acceptable (as in they mean the same thing)?

[These](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=provide%20us%20the%20ability%2Cprovide%20us%20with%20the%20ability&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprovide%20us%20the%20ability%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprovide%20us%20with%20the%20ability%3B%2Cc0) are the Ngram results which shows a drastic difference between the usage rates. Google search too gives similar results (numbers of the latter exceed numbers of the former).

If they are different, I would like to know what idea 'with' emphasizes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Provide" isn't normally used that way. When it means "to supply or to make available", it takes a prepositional phrase introduced by *to* or *for*.

> Vitamin C provides the ability to resist disease *to us*.

You use *with* when it means to make something available.

> "[W]hen *provide* is used transitively to mean "to make
>   something available to," the thing being provided is
>   usually named in a prepositional phrase introduced by
>   *with*:
>
> The bereaved woman was provided with a collection
>   of gruesome anecdotes... "
>
> **Webster's Dictionary of English Usage**

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable but one is more preferred over the other as Ngram confirms.  Adding 'with' doesn't change the meaning of the sentence.